# Could you recommend an anthology of modern philosophy texts?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

Could you recommend an anthology of modern philosophy texts? I was tempted to buy the book *Modern Philosophy: An Anthology of Primary Sources* by Roger Arlew, but it is out of my financial reach. Do you know of any cheaper but equally good alternatives? Thank you very much!

Comment: For free and excellent : https://www.utm.edu/staff/jfieser/class/

Comment: Textbooks are infuriatingly expensive and scholarly journals price for libraries. It's really a scandal. However, if you look on Google or Amazon for earlier editions on the used book market, textbook prices fall dramatically, since they are usually overprinted. I see the Arlew anthology, 2E on Amazon used for $4.95.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, affordability of scholarly publications is really a stifling problem. This is so for universities and libraries, let alone individuals. It comprises intricate issues with a number of stakeholders, deeply rooted in our political and economical presumptions. On the other side, there is an open access initiative, worthy of high praise, that serves, at least partly, as a remedy.

I would like to put down a broader note, considering that you might need more than the book you have mentioned.

You may check out the following websites for the contents of the book:

- [Internet Archive](https://www.gutenberg.org/)
- [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/)
- [Wikisource](https://wikisource.org/)

As for supporting material, you may find many Greek and Roman texts, perhaps more than you would ask for, with parallel translations in:

- [Perseus Digital Library](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/)

Also [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/) offers many journal articles for free to read.

As might be expected, commercial products are often cosier for a reader. However, by a freeware LaTeX editor or an older version of MS Word, you might turn the open source material into texts you would enjoy, and indeed, that would be a vastly valuable study of the subjects in itself.

I would recommend you to follow [Coursera](https://coursera.org/) courses in the meantime.